# How to extract only article body from knowledge graph api in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-knowledge-graph

I am trying to get only the article body from json-ld in php but i can't understand how.

I'm not too familiar with encoding and decoding json from php, so nothing seems to work.

```
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/0dl567",
        "name": "Taylor Swift",
        "@type": [
          "Thing",
          "Person"
        ],
        "description": "Singer-songwriter",
        "image": {
          "contentUrl": "https://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmVDAhjhWnN2OWys2ZMO3PGAhupp5tN2LwF_BJmiHgi19hf8Ku",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift",
          "license": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0"
        },
        "detailedDescription": {
          "articleBody": "Taylor Alison Swift is an American singer-songwriter and actress. Raised in Wyomissing, Pennsylvania, she moved to Nashville, Tennessee, at the age of 14 to pursue a career in country music. ",
          "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift",
          "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
        },
        "url": "http://taylorswift.com/"
      },
      "resultScore": 896.576599
    }
  ]
}
```

I only need the article body which is "Taylor Alison Swift is an American singer-songwriter and actress...". How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode this string with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) then it's just picking up your needs from an array. E.g.

```
$j = '{"@context": {"@vocab": "http://schema.org/", "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/", "resultScore": "goog:resultScore" }}';

$arr = json_decode($j, true);

echo $arr['@context']['goog'];
```

For `articleBody` it should be:

```
$arr['itemListElement'][0]['result']['detailedDescription']['articleBody']
```

Comment: It says 'Undefined index: @itemListElement' Here is my modified code: <?php
$url = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=taylor+swift&key=<MY API KEY>&limit=1&indent=True';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response['@itemListElement']['result']['detailedDescription']['articleBody'];
?>

Comment: But now it shows 'Undefined index: result'. What might be causing the problem?

Comment: try `['itemListElement'][0]['result']['detailedDescription']['articleBody']`